# How to change IME Action dynamically in android for webkit

Tags: android, webkit

When I tap on input[type=number] element in HTML page (Note: html page has only one input element), the keyboard appear with "NEXT" button.

How can I change this NEXT button to DONE/OK or hide it in android 2.3, is it possible to change/hide it?

Answer (score 0):

you can change the ime options by using below code:

> input type="text" style="-ms-image-mode: active; ime-mode: active;

Hope it will help. Thanks